# how to make Google Drive put files in old directory (~/Google Drive/) instead of new directory (~/Google Drive/My Drive/)

Tags: macos, unix, sync, google-drive

## Background

I am using Google Drive for Desktop on two Mac laptops. Both are running "Catalina" (MacOS 10.15). I would like to be able to sync between them and have the filepaths be the same on both (i.e., if `a.txt` is at `~/Google Drive/a.txt` on one computer I want it to be same on the other).

I just set up the second one a few weeks ago (the first was set up a couple years ago). On this second one, Google Drive has decided to store files not in `~/Google Drive/` but rather in `~/Google Drive/My Drive/`. This has caused filepaths that are correct on the first computer to be wrong on the second computer. (The problem manifests itself in using BibDesk, where links to PDFs that work on the first computer do not work on the second computer.)

## Question

Is there a way to tell Google Drive to eliminate the `My Drive` subdirectory and just use `~/Google Drive/` as it still does on the first computer? Or is there a clever way to set up symlinks to make the filepaths work? (The trouble is I can't just say `ln -s "~/Google Drive/My Drive/" ~/Google\ Drive` on the second computer because there is already a directory with that name.)

To be clear, I am *not* having trouble syncing files between the computers. That works fine. It's just that I want the filepath of a given file to be **exactly the same** on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I think I know the solution:

Computer 2: I realized that it was just a symlink to `My Drive` sitting inside the `Google Drive` folder, so I deleted that whole folder and then wrote `ln -s "~/Google Drive/My Drive/" ~/Google\ Drive`. That fixed the issue with `BibDesk`.

Computer 1: Then, to make BibDesk links on the first computer still work, I had to write `ln -s "Google Drive" "My Drive"`.

Having these two symlinks makes them work on either computer whether the filepath begins with Google Drive or My Drive.

Comment: Oh no, this is not the right answer at all. I've now realized that whatever I did has broken all the BibDesk file-links on my home computer!

Comment: I've now discovered that if on the first computer (my home computer) I now create a symlink `ln -s Google\ Drive My\ Drive` it works. Somehow each computer is messing with the BibDesk filepaths. Having these two symlinks makes them work on either computer whether the filepath begins with `Google Drive` or `My Drive`. I will edit my answer accordingly.